# react native open api generated client [Unhandled promise rejection: Error: not implemented]

Tags: react-native, openapi

I have a hello world with open api from [this tutorial](https://medium.com/tribalscale/how-to-automate-api-code-generation-openapi-swagger-and-boost-productivity-1176a0056d8a)

[API schema is in here as JSON](https://petstore3.swagger.io/api/v3/openapi.json)

as in the tutorial I just call the generated API client

```
  <Button title='API' onPress={()=> Api.Pet.getPetById(42)}/>
```

but is not working and getting the error

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: not implemented]
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob/URL.js:195:10 in get__search
at Api/generated/common.ts:91:48 in setSearchParams
at Api/generated/api.ts:502:12 in getPetById
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because React Native/iOS doesn't fully implement the URLSearchParams. See here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/23922

You need to polyfill it.

```
yarn add react-native-url-polyfill
```

then

```
import 'react-native-url-polyfill/auto';
```

at the top of your entry file.